# how to configure opencv 1.2 in visual c++?

Tags: visual-c++, configuration, opencv

i  am trying to do a project in visual c++ using opencv library of version 1.2. but i cannot proceed forward due to the difficulty in configuring opencv 1.2 in vc++.please anybody help me....

Answer (score 2):

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VisualC%2B%2B

Answer (score 0):

The [procedure for OpenCV 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179222/how-to-install-opencv-2-0-on-win32) will probably work.  Good luck.