# The application was unable to start correctly (0*0150002) - OpenCv

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm working on a project written in opencv (2.1) using cpp 2010. When I try to debug it I get the following error:

> 'FaceTracker.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\hodhod\Documents\Jam3a\PROJECT-2012!!\FindSymetryInFaces\FaceTracker\FaceTracker\Debug\FaceTracker.exe', Symbols loaded.
>   'FaceTracker.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
>   'FaceTracker.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
>   'FaceTracker.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
>   'FaceTracker.exe': Loaded 'C:\OpenCV2.1\bin\cv210d.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
>   The program '[4556] FaceTracker.exe: Native' has exited with code -1072365566 (0xc0150002).

And shows me the following message:

> The application was unable to start correctly (0*0150002). Click Ok to close the application.

How can I solve it?

(I solved it, check the comments.)

Comment: I Solved It.
I went to Project -> Proporties -> Linker-> Input -> Additional Dependencies And Changed it from :

    cv210d.lib;
    cvaux210d.lib;
    cxcore210d.lib;
    highgui210d.lib;
    ml210d.lib;

to:

    cv210.lib;
    cvaux210.lib;
    cxcore210.lib;
    highgui210.lib;
    ml210.lib;
    opencv_ffmpeg210.lib;

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to debug an external library (OpenCV) in Visual C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720953/how-to-debug-an-external-library-opencv-in-visual-c)

Answer (score 1):

(Answered by the OP in the comments. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> I Solved It. I went to `Project -> Proporties -> Linker-> Input -> Additional Dependencies` And Changed it from :

```
cv210d.lib; cvaux210d.lib; cxcore210d.lib; highgui210d.lib; ml210d.lib;
```

> to:

```
cv210.lib; cvaux210.lib; cxcore210.lib; highgui210.lib; ml210.lib; opencv_ffmpeg210.lib;
```

Comment: please do the opencv community a favour, and refrain from answering or editing such outdated questions, that should better be buried under a big rock.