# Error: No symbols loaded for opencv_world310.dll in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

I'm writing program using OpenCV-3.1.0 in Visual Studio 2015. Most of the operations work fine, however, I get an Access Violation error. I have debugged the project, after faceClassifier.load("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml") is executed, the Locals windows displays "Information not available, no symbols loaded for opencv_world310.dll". Here's the code:

```
#include "opencv2/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/videoio.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void detectAndDisplay(Mat);

int main()
{
    Mat img = imread("faces.jpg");
    detectAndDisplay(img);
    return 0;
}


void detectAndDisplay(Mat img)
{
    CascadeClassifier faceClassifier;
    faceClassifier.load("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");
    vector<Rect> faces;
    Mat gray;
    cvtColor(img, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    faceClassifier.detectMultiScale(gray, faces,1.1,3,0);

    for (int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++)
    {
        Point center(faces[i].x + faces[i].width*0.5, faces[i].y + faces[i].height*0.5);
        ellipse(img, center, Size(faces[i].width*0.5, faces[i].height*0.5), 0, 0, 360, Scalar(255, 0, 255), 4, 8, 0);
    }

    namedWindow("Faces", 1);

    while (true)
    {
        imshow("Faces", img);
        if (waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did anyone ever figure out this problem I am getting the same one I believe

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the OpenCV debug libraries. The normal libraries do not contain debug information.

The debug libraries have a **d** before `.dll` or `.lib`

Try

> opencv_world310d.dll

Comment: The "Additional Dependencies" field contains: "opencv_world310.lib;opencv_world310d.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)". This has the debug library included.

Comment: For debug builds you should only use the debug libraries. Your **Additional Dependencies** field should only contain the `opencv_world310d.lib`. Make also sure that your app is able to locate the `opencv_world310d.dll`.

Comment: As you suggested, I have removed "opencv_world.lib" from Additional Dependencies. However, it still says "No symbols loaded for opencv_world310d.dll". How do I make sure that my app is able is able to locate the opencv_world310d.dll?

Comment: If you actually want to debug into the OpenCV library, I think you have to build the `.PDB` files (debug database, as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720953/how-to-debug-an-external-library-opencv-in-visual-c). Is the `haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml` in your output directory?

Comment: It is in the same directory as of "faces.jpg". "faces.jpg" loads successfully. I think building `.PDB` files is not necessary. I just want to run the project.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your error on my machine (the snippet runs without error). How did you check that the image loaded successfully? I would recommend you to add checks like `if (img.data == nullptr) return 1;` and `if (faceClassifier.empty()) return;`

Comment: I loaded the image and displayed it on namedWindow. Worked without error.

Comment: Here are my project settings:

Configuration: All Configurations
Platform: x64
Additional Include Directories: $(OPENCV_DIR)\build\include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)
Additional Library Directories: $(OPENCV_DIR)\build\include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)
Additional Dependencies: opencv_world310d.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)
Target Machine: MACHINEX64(/MACHINE:X64)

Comment: I have discovered that only the debug information is not available for the CascadeClassifier. If I don't debug the project and run it, it runs without error. Thank you for your help btw.