# i have ucrtbased.dll and opencv_world3110d.dll but the program cant find or open the PDB files from

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, opencv3.1

i have problem in c++ opencv3.1.0 in visual studio 2015. when i run my code why my program always give output : ucrtbased.dll cannot find or open the PDB file and opencv_world310d.dll cannot find or open the PDB file. I have to try so many sollution but the program always cant find or open pdb file from uctbased and opencv_world310d only. please if you have any sollution please help me, this is my full output:

'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Wu\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Project2\x64\Debug\Project2.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\OpenCV310\build\x64\vc14\bin\opencv_world310d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\lpk.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\usp10.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\comdlg32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7601.17514_none_a4d6a923711520a9\comctl32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvfw32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmm.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\avifil32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msacm32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\avicap32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\version.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp140d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbased.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\api-ms-win-core-timezone-l1-1-0.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\api-ms-win-core-file-l2-1-0.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-1.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\api-ms-win-core-file-l1-2-0.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\concrt140d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msctf.dll'. Symbols loaded.

***** VIDEOINPUT LIBRARY - 0.1995 - TFW07 *****

Exception thrown at 0x000007FEFD849E5D in Project2.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x000000000018DD70.
Unhandled exception at 0x000007FEFD849E5D in Project2.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x000000000018DD70.

The program '[5768] Project2.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
i hope anyone can help me to fix this problem, thanks.

Comment: This (Unhandled exception) problem is unrelated to the pdb missing warning.

Comment: ***Cannot find or open the PDB file.*** Means since it can't find the debug symbols you will not be able to easily debug the internals of opencv. It has no effect on execution

Comment: @drescherjm thanks for answer my question:)
if unhandled exception problem is unrelated to the pdb missing warning what the problem with my visual studio? :( coz when i run code usually the program stop and ask me to break/continue (but i cant continue) and after that the program show me that output :(
im very new at opencv

Comment: ***missing warning what the problem with my visual studio?*** No it's not a problem with Visual Studio either. The problem that is causing the  (Unhandled exception)  is most likely a bug in your c++ program.

Comment: Enable break on c++ exceptions in Visual Studio Exceptions to get Visual Studio to stop at this error.  Then follow the callstack up to the line of your code causing the exception.

Comment: i hv to try all solution now, but my program still show output "opencv_world310.dll cannot find or open the PDB file"

Comment: That is expected. You will not have debug symbols for a release dll. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36204421/error-no-symbols-loaded-for-opencv-world310-dll-in-visual-studio

Comment: Make sure you are not using the release dlls in your debug application or debug dlls in your release application. Both can and will cause your program to randomly crash because the debug heap is not compatible with the release heap.

Comment: i have implement only opencv_world310.dll in the release
and opencv_world310d.dll only in debug but the result is the same, i really dont know what to do now

Comment: Again I say whatever problem you are having is not related to the `pdb` file warning message.