# BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 bgm->apply throws exception in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, opencv, visual-c++, access-violation

I'm new to C++ and opencv and having difficulty running the background subtractor model. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 (VC++) and opencv 3.2.

I need to use `BackgroundSubtractorMOG2` and it creates the model fine but throws exception when I pass it a new frame that is converted from an encoded image (because I'm using a USB3 camera that doesn't allow direct reading of frame by opencv) to cv::Mat. The code snippet is below

```
if (EncodeRawImage(pRawImage, &frameDesc, imageFormat, &pEncodedImage, &encodedImageSize) == SUCCESS) {
    // Convert current raw image to openCV Mat format for analysis
    auto store = gcnew cli::array<Byte>(encodedImageSize);
    System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::Copy(IntPtr(pEncodedImage), store, 0, encodedImageSize);
    auto stream = gcnew System::IO::MemoryStream(store);

    System::Drawing::Bitmap^ bitmapFrame = safe_cast<System::Drawing::Bitmap ^> (Image::FromStream(stream));
    Mat imgBuf = Mat(bitmapFrame->Width, bitmapFrame->Height, CV_8U, pEncodedImage);
    Mat imgMat = imdecode(imgBuf, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);             

    bgm->apply(imgMat , fgMaskMOG);
    returnCode = 1;
 }
```

The exception is

> owner 0x0000023afa2a2ec0 Information not available, no symbols loaded for opencv_world320d.dll>   cv::detail::PtrOwner *
>
> stored    0x0000023afa29baa0 Information not available, no symbols loaded for opencv_world320d.dll>   cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 *

Even though the opencv320d.lib are linked properly and a few other basic opencv samples run for me in the same program (e.g., cv::subtract, cv::calcHist etc). I wonder if it because the image size is too large (4608x3288) and bitmpaFrame that I'm creating may have an issue?

Or if I'm trying to access image data in the stream/memory in a way that is not allowed?

Comment: I've also included #include "opencv2/video/background_segm.hpp" and did cv::Mat fgMaskMOG; Ptr<BackgroundSubtractorMOG2> bgm;bgm = createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2();

Comment: You're probably linking to OpenCV build with vc14. What's the folder of opencv_world320d.lib?

Comment: Hi Miki yes actually its linking the vc14 and the folder is C:\OPENCV320\opencv\build\x64\vc14\lib. But there is no other build in the build folder other than vc14? I don't have much knowledge about the build versions which I need to study more about :(

Comment: OpenCV 3.3 should have the prebuild binary for vs2017. You'd better install that

Comment: OK thanks that means it's not the code problem in the section I copied :). I also have the 3.3 version downloaded, I'll link that and see if that fixes this problem. Thanks

Comment: I've no idea if your code is working with all that CLI stuff... for sure you linked the wrong OpenCV version

Comment: I installed and configured almost identical to the settings given in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M-VHaLHC4XI. The only thing I didn't do was not built it using cmake like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M-VHaLHC4XI. The example in first link works fine even some basic functions (subtract, calcHist, histmatch) work fine and show results but when it comes to bgm->apply it shows this error. I also suspect the linking is problematic (but I only have vc14 directory in build folder :( ). I do have a lot of warnings telling me something like "function compiled as native" though? Im installing 3.3

Comment: Trying this one also but doesn't seem to work :S https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36204421/error-no-symbols-loaded-for-opencv-world310-dll-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the Information not found string is still there when I do the breakpoint, I just found that the model was throwing exception because of large image size as I mentioned in my original question (4608x3288). I resizes the image (`resize(newImageMat, newImageMat, cv::Size(1000, 1000 * newImageMat.rows / newImageMat.cols), INTER_LINEAR);`) and the error is gone and the model learns and shows the result. The text maybe a Visual Studio bug since I was reading about a similar issue here https://stackoverflow.com/a/7736034/3377101?